# What is a Linear Set of Points.

Tags: real-analysis, terminology

According to the classroom notes "Uniformly Continuous Linear Set" in American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 62. No. 8(Oct., 1955) pp. 579-580, Author: Norman Levine
He let E denotes a Linear Set of Points but without the definition of it.
So I would like to know its definition and the example of such a set like that. Thank you for all answers.

Answer (score 2):

In context, a linear set $E$ appears to just be some $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

(See, in particular, the proofs of theorem 2 and 3.)

In terms of examples:

- $\mathbb{Z}$
- $[0,1]$
- $\mathbb{R}$

*Remark:* the author also uses a notation that may be confusing. In the author's notation $A+B$ for $A,B\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ refers to $A\cup B$. And $A-B$ refers to $A \setminus B$. (In a lot of modern real/harmonic analysis texts $A+B := \{x = a+b: a\in A, b\in B\}$ and similarly $A-B$.)

*Remark 2:* I am pretty confident that the results mentioned can be easily generalised to a larger class of uniform spaces.